# Is there a way to know how much do I owe to AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm struggling to find out how much I've spent so far with Amazon Web Services. What I found is they'll bill me each month (and then I'll find out). But do they have any billing statistics that updates more frequently then once per month?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about AWS services

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your [Account Activity](https://aws-portal.amazon.com/gp/aws/developer/account/index.html?action=activity-summary) shows your current charges, itemized by service and by usage type.

It is updated daily.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I've seen this page. But for now it says "You have no activity for this period". I've opened an account a few hours ago. If it gets updated daily, hopefully I'll see some data tomorrow. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, up-to-date billing is available here:

https://portal.aws.amazon.com/gp/aws/developer/account?ie=UTF8&action=activity-summary

once you log into your aws console. Its all available programatically if you prefer:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/about/programaccess.html